# Tips for debugging stack corruptions (Visual Studio)

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

I have a somehow working program (written only in C) - it does what it should do while it is running, but crashes at exit. 
I have a hint, in the form of:

> "run time check failure 2 stack around the variable was corrupted"

I never debugged for such errors (or even used the Visual Studio debugger) so I don't know where to start. I set up some breakpoints around the function call which generates the stack corruption and added watches for the variables used for that call and also for the registers (I especially looked for EBP, ESP alteration, but I checked them all) but they have the correct values. I also put break points in that function but still couldn't see anything suspicious.

Is there a way to see the stack and how values are pushed, accessed and pop-ed? Also, what should I be looking for when I deal with such things?

The problem is caused by a DLL (I have access to it's code). The DLL uses __stdcall convention for it's functions and it seems that they clean up the stack correctly, but I'm willing to believe that it doesn't and start looking at the stack before, during and after this calls. Is this a good starting point? But still, how do I do this? The Stack Frame window isn't particularly helpful (or I don't know how to use it).

EDIT: I did it manually (looking at the code, drawing my stack) and find some issues were the stack frame wasn't set up properly. Fixed it. Still curious about some debugger features that would have made this faster.

Comment: Check the stack-trace for the last function that was called before the SO occurred. If no stack-trace is at hand, then check the value of the PC register (sometimes also called IP register), and view the dis-assembly at the memory pointed by this register, in order to find the function at which the SO has occurred.

Comment: @barakmanos I know where it occurs (I stripped all other function calls from my program so I'm left only with the bad one). It also returns correctly (the data it returns is valid). That's why I think that it fails to clean up the stack (or cleans up too much). The Call Stack displays only what and from where is called. Not what's pushed/poped. Going manually through the code (pen and paper style) it seems like the clean up is done correctly, but that's not an accurate way of testing it. Should I switch to OllyDbg?

Comment: You can read about detection of stack corruption algorithm here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c.aspx (Security Checks). So, if you find that some function call causes this, you need to continue your investigation inside this function, by commenting off its different parts. Of course, if you have source code of this library available and can change and rebuild it.